# Javascript regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

The below function works for date a of format `yyyy-MM-dd` within the range `1900-01-30` to `2099-12-31`.

How do change I change it to work for a date within the range `1900-01-30` to `9999-12-31`?

```
function validateDateFormat(val)
{
    var patt =/^((19|20)\d\d)[- \-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    var temp = val;
    if(isNaN(temp.match(patt)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/` should work just fine.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/wJ7oG8)

```
Y 9999-12-31
Y 2013-12-12
Y 1990-01-01
N 1800-01-01
Y 1900-01-01
N 10000-12-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var patt =/^((19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2})[- \-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
```

Comment: Your regexp will also match years between 1000 and 1900

Comment: Thank you, I already fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the two first numbers of the year :

```
var patt =/^((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[- \-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
```